# Sort NSMutableArray and sort another NSMutableArray along

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays

It's possible to sort an array like this:

```
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"5",@"1",@"7,@"9",@"4", nil];
```

to (start big ends small):

```
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"9",@"7",@"5,@"4",@"1", nil];
```

Is it also possible to sort two arrays:

```
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"5",@"1",@"7",@"9",@"4", nil];
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Andy",@"Mike",@"Bob",@"Amy",@"Alex", nil];
```

to (from big to small, but `Andy` got `5` point, `Mike` got `1` and so on):

```
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"9",@"7",@"5",@"4",@"1", nil];
MutableArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Amy",@"Bob",@"Andy",@"Alex",@"Mike", nil];
```

Is it possible to order them as a couple?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you'd better to take a look at nsdictionary, it seems...

Comment: Yes its called sorting

Comment: Because an NSDictionary can hold keys (players) and values (scores). So when you sort one, you automatically sort both.

Comment: If you don't want a dictionary, objects would work too. (Anything's better than matching parallel arrays.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example how to sort `arrayOne` ascending and sort `arrayTwo` along:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOne  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"5",@"1",@"7",@"9",@"4", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayTwo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Andy",@"Mike",@"Bob",@"Amy",@"Alex", nil];

NSDictionary *temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayTwo forKeys:arrayOne];
NSArray *sortedArrayOne = [[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *sortedArrayTwo = [temp objectsForKeys:sortedArrayOne notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArrayOne);
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArrayTwo);
```

Workflow:
Create dictionary from the arrays `->` sort dictionary `->` create arrays from dictionary.

**EDIT**

Use `NSSortDescriptor` with `ascending:NO` to sort descending, quick example:

```
NSDictionary *temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayTwo forKeys:arrayOne];
NSSortDescriptor *theDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];    
NSArray *sortedArrayOne = [[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theDescriptor]];
NSArray *sortedArrayTwo = [temp objectsForKeys:sortedArrayOne notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: Thanks :) works great :) but is it possible to do the opposite? instead of 1,4,5,7,9 then get it to 9,7,5,4,1 (with names)?

Comment: Added quick example how to sort descending.

Comment: if i use the number 22, it'll be places between 1 and 4.. how to change that?

Comment: Replace `@selector(compare:)` by `@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)`.

Comment: Sry for all this.. but: if i use the number 22, it'll be places between 1 and 4.. how can I change that??

Comment: : if i use the number 22, it'll be places between 1 and 4.. how can I change that??

Comment: Like mentioned above, replacing `@selector(compare:)` by `@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)` should solve the sorting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create some new object let's say `Player` with ivars `name` and `score` and store instances of that class in array. Then you'll be able to sort that array as you want for any point in your code like so:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] ;
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedByName = [players sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

or by score:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO] ;
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedByName = [players sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```