# Sort 2 arrays? Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, string, sorting

I have 2 arrays, one of NSNumber objects, and one of NSString objects. I wan't to alphabetically sort the array of NSString objects, and that i can achieve, but the tricky part is, that the NSNumbers "match" the NSString objects. For instance:

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jones", @"Marc", @"Miles"];

NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], [NSNumber numberWithInt:15]];
```

The above means, that the number 5 is "linked" with the string "Jones". So when i alphabetically sort the array of strings, the numbers need to move as well. So if i move Jones to index 2, i need to move the number 5 to index 2, in the other array.

Hope it makes sense, i really cant wrap my head around this :)
Thanks on advance

Comment: Looks like the answer to this one will sort you out: [Sorting 2 NSArrays together side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436927/sorting-2-nsarrays-together-side-by-side)

Comment: can you tell me how your number is linked with sting?

Comment: Also, this question seems to pop up quite frequently - I am curious as to which situations lead to this construct? Why not build an object that has both elements, and sort it in one go?

Comment: If both values can never be in same object then you should make sure that, John and 5 both values are should be in the same place in your array! Other than try to add those values into a single object and then sort it. As said by @Monolo

Comment: Why isnt this made inside a dictionary?

Comment: Ah, never thought of making an object that has a number and string as properties and just add them to the array and sort the string, great solution and great link if i have it too deeply implemented to change it. Thanks monolo!