# Sort multiple NSArray at the same time - iOS

Tags: objective-c, sorting, floating-point, nsarray, comparator

I have an iOS application which downloads some data from a server. The data includes three main segments: Name (string), address (string) and distance (float).

The said data is stored in three simple `NSArray`. However I would like to sort the data, so that the results are shown in the following format: Lowest distance first -> highest distance.

I am using Apple's `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method to sort the distance array. However I have one problem... how can I perform the same sort actions on the other two `NSArray` so that the data is shown correctly?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
NSArray *nameData = // string data.....
NSArray *addressData = // string data.....
NSArray *distanceData = // float data.....

distanceData = [distanceData sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    else if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

As you can see, the above code will sort the "distanceData" array and thats great, but if I only sort the distance array, then the other two arrays will not be in the correct order. So how can I sort the other two array?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Have you tried with Object class ?

Comment: As per my understanding of your question you could create 3 different NSThread to sort NSArray parallel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting two NSArrays together side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436927/sorting-two-nsarrays-together-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one class named `Person` of type `NSObject` with properties `name`, `address`, `distance`

Person.h

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float distance;

@end
```

Person.m

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize name;
@synthesize address;
@synthesize distance;

@end
```

In your view controller, take only 1 array with Person class' object instead of 3 arrays.

```
arrPersons = //...Person objects;
```

Here, you'll get all values.
For Eg.

```
Person *p = [arrPersons objectAtIndex:0];
//p.name
//p.address
//p.distance
```

In this way, you have multiple values of Person object. Based on its property named `distance`, you can perform sorting.

So, you'll get updated Person objects. In this objects, all values will have been sorted.

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [arrPersons sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    float first = [(Person*)a distance];
    float second = [(Person*)b distance];
    return first > second; //Here, you can use > or < as per ASC or DESC
}];
```

Hope, you'll get idea. As well it'll fulfil your needs.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you add objects to this? Is there a ```addObject``` method like there is with ```NSMutableArray```? Also, I just thought, why not create an array of arrays instead like: ```@[@[name, address, distance], [@[name, address, distance], etc...]```??

Comment: Ok having played around with this for a bit now, I got it working. And thank you so much!!! For so long.... I have been saving my JSON parsing data to multiple arrays.... which has made sorting and other similar actions quite hard. Now I can just use a class and use the dot property to access the data I need..... ah man this is going to help so much :) Thanks.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff : It's my pleasure buddy.. Glad to help you. :) 
Did you get how to add objects into array with properties ?

Comment: Yeah I got that in the end. Thanks :)